# Understanding Bézout's identity

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to understand a proof of Bézout's identity ($gcd(a,b)=$ smallest linear combination of $a$ and $b$), and I'm having some trouble following the last step.

The proof goes by:

Let $m=sa+tb$ be the smallest linear combination of $a$ and $b$

If we can prove $m\leq gcd(a,b)$ and $m \geq gcd(a,b)$, then it is implied that $m=gcd(a,b)$.

The first inequality follows easily so $gcd(a,b)\leq m$, but I'm having trouble proving the second one.

If $m=sa+tb$, then $a=q(sa+tb)+r$, $r=(1-qs)a+(-qt)b$ and since ($r<m$), $r$ must be zero.

It follows to show similarly that both $m|a$ and $m|b$, and from that it reaches the conclusion that $m\leq gcd(a,b)$, and this is where I'm confused. Why does $m|a$ and $m|b$ imply $m\leq gcd(a,b)$?

Comment: The *greatest* common divisor is $\ge$ every common divisor.

Comment: It should say  the smallest *positive* combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m\mid a$ and $m\mid b$, then $m$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. By definition $\gcd(a,b)$ is the **largest** common divisor of $a$ and $b$, so $\gcd(a,b)\ge m$.